# RTK Query update data client side

Tags: rtk-query

I have a React Component displaying a list of items that I'm getting from an API using RTK Query. I can select/unselect items from this list, I'm currently storing this list in redux with the current selected state of each items because I need the selected items elsewhere in the app. Is it the right approach for this kind of client data manipulation ?

Answer (score 0):

you provide a minimum data so I'm not sure about your question. however
what I understand is your data comes from and RTK query and that data will cache so you want to know storing the list separately in redux store is right or not?

many things comes up.
first if you need the list it self no there is no need to cache it else where unless you fetch that data once and for all but you should know that RTK Hooks
will always return the cached data unless you tell them to remove it (like with `mutation` or `keepUnusedDataFor`).
so for example you can use `useGetMySelectListQuery` as many time as you want.

but if you need to select the items from the list and later in some other page or component and start where you left off yes you should use redux to keep track of changes.

remember you don't always have to use redux maybe your problem solved with something like [this](https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components#lifting-state-up-by-example)